# How to get header.php drupal 7

Tags: theming

I have the next files .tpl.php in my drupal7:

- page-front.tpl.php
- page.tpl.php
- page-taxonomy.tpl.php

I want include a header.php and footer.php  with the follow way but is not working:

```
<?php include_once($theme_path.'/include/header.php');?>
```

How can I get common files from a tpl.php?

Comment: Using template_preprocess_page sounds like a better way to add content to pages. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hi rreiss,  sorry but I am new with drupal, I´ve worked with wordpress but drupal is my first time to work. 

why do you think is best choice using template_preprocess_page??
how it should be implemented?

Kind regards!

Comment: It depends on the things you're adding in those files, but I assume that we're taking about elements that are related to the appearance of those pages and not to its functionality (module vs. theme). In Drupal if you want to add page logic you should use template_preprocss_page, for example - you can add new variable (probably a renderable array) to the page variavles ($vars['foo']) and print it in the template file if it exists. Hope that's clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`drupal_get_path()`](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=drupal_get_path), e.g.

```
<?php include_once drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/include/header.php'; ?>
```

`include_once` isn't a function so no need for parentheses.